# Number of distinct arrangements such that $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5 = 20$ subject to given conditions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4<n_5$ be positive integers such that $$n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=20$$ then the number of such distinct arrangements $(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)$ is?

So I tried this by generating a function, as following

Since $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4<n_5$ , I set

$$n_2=n_1+k$$
$$n_3=n_2+p = n_1+p+k$$
$$n_4=n_3+q=n_1+p+k+q$$
$$n_5=n_4+r=n_1+p+k+q+r$$

So, putting this in the original equation I got

$$5n_1+4k+3p+2q+r = 20$$

where $n_1,p,q,r,k > 0$

Now my question is, what would be the upper limit in the series that I generate for this.
I found another answer here that followed the same approach as I did (link: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2401439) and then  solved this by taking the limit of the upper variable as infinity and thus this is a summation of an infinite geometric series of which I take the coefficient of $x^{20}$ to find my required answer.

But I can't understand why should I take the limit as infinity in this particular question, and how to understand taking upper limits in further problems.

My book states

> If upper limit of the variable is more than or equal to the sum required, then the upper limit of the variable can be taken as infinity.
>
> If the upper limit of a variable is less than the sum required and the lower limit of the variable is non-negative, then the upper limit of that variable is that given in the problem.

I don't quite understand how it translates to this question, I mean how is it that I know that the upper limits of $n_1,k,p,q,r$ are greater than or equal to the sum required so as to take it as infinity?

Also can someone recommend further resources for studying these kind of questions (explained simply, I'm a high schooler).

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated.  We must have $n_1≥1, n_2≥2$ and so on, and $1+2+3+4+5=15$ already so you just have to distribute $5$ amongst those values, while respecting the rules.  Thus, if, say, you increase $n_1$ by $1$ you must add $1$ to each of the other elements.  Not a lot of ways to do that.

Comment: Should say:  With bigger values, I can imagine that some algebraic machinery is helpful.  Here, I think it gets in the way.

Comment: @lulu yes i just want a general method for problems with let's say where the sum = 70

Comment: @lulu Also, this is for a competitive exam, so if I miss just a single value while calculating manually it would be a disaster...much better to use algebraic manipulation

Comment: Ah, there I strongly disagree.  Well, it depends what tools you have.  If you have high powered algebraic software (Wolfram Alpha or the equivalent) then sure.  Generating functions are easy to program and the machine does all the hard work for you.  But my method is effortlessly worked by hand whereas multiplying those power series by hand is profoundly error prone.

Comment: But I don't understand your question about taking some limit.   The generating function method is just a convenient way of handling formal arithmetic operations...there is no limit involved.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @lulu isn't there an upper limit involved in the series? I have quite a few examples of them in my books...i can show a few of them tomorrow when I wake up

Comment: To stress: In the multiplication, you should ignore all the terms of higher order than you need.  Here,  factoring out the straight powers of $x$ you are just looking for the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1 + x^5) (1 + x^4) (1 + x^3) (1 + x^2 + x^4) (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)$.  No infinities involved.

Comment: @lulu This is explained in the accepted answer to the linked question.

Comment: @saulspatz  Am I missing something?  There is never any limit to take.  The formal power series is just a helpful way of organizing the operations we need to perform.  At no point should you ever be performing an infinite number of operations.

Comment: @lulu I meant in the series in the linked question, the answer states that the required ans is the coeff of $x^20$ in multiplication of infinite geometrical series. I'm not talking about performing infinite operations

Comment: @lulu True, but sometimes you can extend the series to infinite geometric series and get simpler expressions.  That's what the linked answer claims to do.  (I haven't checked it.)  You have to be sure that the terms you add don't lead to extraneous solutions.

Comment: @saulspatz  Ah, I'm not seeing that in that solution.  As far as I can see, the author just writes the same product I wrote in an earlier comment and then (sensibly) punts the calculation over to WA.

Comment: @lulu Yes, you're right.  I stopped reading too soon.

Comment: To be clear, the generating function method is clearly superior for values signficantly larger than $20$.  For $70$ I would not care to try to enumerate the relevant $5-$ tuples.  But [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+1%2F%28%281-x%5E5%29%281-x%5E4%29%281-x%5E3%29%281-x%5E2%29%281-x%29%29) has no difficulty.  The answer to that problem would be the coefficient of $x^{55}$, so $5260$.  For values like $10^6$ or whatever, neither method is particularly attractive.  If forced to do it, I guess I'd use Stars and Bars, plus Inclusion Exclusion

Comment: Generally, sorted lists of solutions are hard to count with simple generating functions. In this case, when the $n_i$ are positive, there are no solutions, as others have pointed out.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There are 7 solutions to this equation, as from the linked answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401356/how-many-solutions-does-the-equation-n-1-n-2-n-3-n-4-n-5-20-have-in/2401439#2401439

Comment: Oh, was it edited from $10$ to $20?$ In any event, generating functions are not a good approach to this type of question, because of the condition $n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_5.$

Answer (score 4):

Note that we can rewrite the problem as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  n_{\,1}  < n_{\,2}  < n_{\,3}  <  \cdots  < n_{\,q - 1}  < n_{\,q}  \hfill \cr 
  n_{\,1}  + n_{\,2}  + n_{\,3}  +  \cdots  + n_{\,q - 1}  + n_{\,q}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  n_{\,1}  \le n_{\,2}  - 1 \le n_{\,3}  - 2 \le  \cdots  \le n_{\,q - 1}  - \left( {q - 2} \right) \le n_{\,q}  - \left( {q - 1} \right) \hfill \cr 
  n_{\,1}  + \left( {n_{\,2}  - 1} \right) +  \cdots  + \left( {n_{\,q}  - \left( {q - 1} \right)} \right) = s - \left( \matrix{
  q \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  m_{\,1}  \le m_{\,2}  \le  \cdots  \le m_{\,q - 1}  \le m_{\,q}  \hfill \cr 
  m_{\,1}  + m_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + m_{\,q - 1}  + m_{\,q}  = s - \left( \matrix{
  q \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

That means that:
 - if $1 \le m_1$, which means $ m_k \in \mathbb N$, then the number you are looking for is the 
number of partitions of $s -\binom{q}{2}$ into $q$ parts;
 - if $0 \le m_1$, which means $ 0 \le m_k \in \mathbb Z$, then the number you are looking for is the 
number of partitions of $s -\binom{q}{2}$ into at most $q$ parts.

You can then refer to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) about partitions with restricted part size/number and to the vast literature on the subject.

Keeping instead with your approach, which is a valid alternative, we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 < n_{\,1}  < n_{\,2}  < n_{\,3}  <  \cdots  < n_{\,q - 1}  < n_{\,q}  \hfill \cr 
  n_{\,1}  + n_{\,2}  + n_{\,3}  +  \cdots  + n_{\,q - 1}  + n_{\,q}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  1 \le n_{\,1}  = m_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  1 \le m_{\,k}  = n_{\,k}  - n_{\,k - 1} \quad \left| {\;2 \le k \le q} \right. \hfill \cr 
  qm_{\,1}  + \left( {q - 1} \right)m_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + 2m_{\,q - 1}  + 1m_{\,q}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le p_{\,q + 1 - k}  = m_{\,k}  - 1 \hfill \cr 
  1p_{\,1}  + 2p_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + q\,p_{\,q}  = s - \left( \matrix{
  q + 1 \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

In your example with $q=5$ we have that, if we take the polynomial
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(x) = \left( {x^{\,1}  \cdot x^{\,2}  \cdot  \cdots  \cdot x^{\,5} } \right)\underbrace {\left( {x^{\,1}  + x^{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x^{\,5} } \right)\left( {x^{\,1}  + x^{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x^{\,5} } \right) \cdots \left( {x^{\,1}  + x^{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x^{\,5} } \right)}_{s - 1\, \le \,t\,{\rm terms}}  \cr 
  &  =  \cdots  + x^{\left( {\scriptstyle 6 \atop 
  \scriptstyle 2}  \right)} x^{\,1\,k_{\,1} } x^{\,2\,k_{\,2} }  \cdots x^{\,5\,k_{\,5} }  +  \cdots \quad \left| {\;0 \le k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + k_{\,5}  = t} \right. \cr} 
$$
we do get
$$
\left[ {x^{\,s} } \right]P(x) = {\rm number}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\left\{ \matrix{
  1 \le \left( {k_{\,j}  + 1} \right) \hfill \cr 
  1\,\left( {k_{\,1}  + 1} \right) + 2\,\left( {k_{\,2}  + 1} \right) +  \cdots  + 5\left( {k_{\,5}  + 1} \right) = s \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Instead of the above, especially for analysis purposes, we have better to consider the fractional function (which has an infinite power expansion)
$$
F(x) = {x \over {1 - x}}{{x^{\,2} } \over {1 - x^{\,2} }} \cdots {{x^{\,5} } \over {1 - x^{\,5} }} = x^{\left( {\scriptstyle 6 \atop 
  \scriptstyle 2}  \right)} {1 \over {1 - x}}{1 \over {1 - x^{\,2} }} \cdots {1 \over {1 - x^{\,5} }}
$$
and this seems to be what your book is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

This infinity business is just a cleaner way of writing everything out which hides some computation. Instead of writing
$$(x^5+x^{10}+x^{15} + x^{20})(x^4+\cdots + x^{20})(x^3+\cdots)\cdots$$
And explicitly stating that we only need terms $x^k$ with $k\leq 20$ to find the coefficient of $x^{20}$, we can just say find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in
$$\prod_{n=1}^5 \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{nk}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^5 \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} $$
This is probably what is meant by taking "infinity as the upper limit" instead of $20$. It's just really a notational thing.

The reason for using the infinite notation is that we now theoretically have an infinite polynomial, or "formal power series", for which the coefficient of $x^k$ is precisely whatever we are trying to count. Computationally, these notations are the same.